# MVC Entity Framework Models and Relationships

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, viewmodel

im quite new to ASP.net and entity framework. I created a class but im just going to simplify it and take the example class from Microsoft. So here we go. These are all the example classes

```
    public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstMidName { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
}


    public class Instructor
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("FirstName")]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string FirstMidName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Hire Date")]
    public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
    public string FullName
    {
        get { return LastName + ", " + FirstMidName; }
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public virtual OfficeAssignment OfficeAssignment { get; set; }
}





   public class OfficeAssignment
    {
        [Key]
        [ForeignKey("Instructor")]
        public int InstructorID { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50)]
        [Display(Name = "Office Location")]
        public string Location { get; set; }

        public virtual Instructor Instructor { get; set; }
    }




   public class Course


  {
      [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
      [Display(Name = "Number")]
      public int CourseID { get; set; }

      [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
      public string Title { get; set; }

      [Range(0, 5)]
      public int Credits { get; set; }

      public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

      public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<Instructor> Instructors { get; set; }
   }
```

Like i said this is just for a example im trying to get know it.

My First Question: Do you need something like DepartmentID When you already do public virtual Department Department?

Second question: When i have a Collection of data how do i add values or Ids to that collection in the controller i can find this anywhere.

Third Question: Can some one link me a complete MVC example application with proper relationships

Comment: You do not necessarily need to explicitly define FK, but EF will add one behind the scenes if you don't. [Here](https://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/) is an mvc example.And  [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/entity-framework-code-first.aspx) is some good info on working with EF.

Comment: Look This is the first time ever i have gotten a comment and not a complaint thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, SO is more for specific questions, but I feel you on how harsh it can get at times. Try some stuff and come back with followup. There is a wealth of answers on these issues already out here.

Comment: Yep all of it works perfectly Thanks so much